# Custom Timestamps in Laravel

Tags: laravel, timestamp, laravel-5

I want to keep the time record of changes in certain columns of my table. How can I get and save timestamp values in db? I am trying to do it in following way but getting always 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in col_edited_at column.

```
$case->col_edited_at = time();
$case->save();
```

Comment: What is the column type for col_edited_at?

Comment: It  is column name. I am getting it through eloquent.  Column type is timestamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers are correct but I have an idea of a more elegant solution. So you don't have to think about setting the timestamp anymore. Add this to your model and if you change the column it will refresh the `col_edited_at` field:

```php
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model){
        if($model->isDirty('col')){
            $model->col_edited_at = Carbon::now();
        }
    });
}
```

So when the model is getting saved and `col` is dirty (meaning it has changed) the timestamp will be set to the current time.

Usage:

```php
$model = MyModel::find(1);
$model->col = 'foo';
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL timestamp fields by default require the format `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. If you're just wanting to store a unix style "seconds since the epoch" timestamp like that returned by `time()` use an integer field, or else use:

```
$case->col_edited_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$case->save();
```

Comment: Or simply `Carbon::now()`

Answer (score 1):

simply use

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead of `time()`